# Error: class "LL" has no tag member "prepend"

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

I am building a linked list struct and I'm not entirely sure how to call a function that works with a linked list. When I try and call a function, I am told it does not exist when I already have a default constructor in my `struct LL`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;
};
struct LL {
    Node* head;
    void prepend(int data);
};
void LL::prepend(int data) {
    Node* temp = new Node();
    temp -> data = data;
    temp -> next = head;
    head = temp;
}
int main() {
    struct LL::prepend(3);
    return 0;
}
```

In my `main` function `struct LL::prepend(3);` is where I get the error, even though `prepend` is a member of `LL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LL::prepend` is not static member function of `struct LL`, you have to call it through object

```
int main() {
    LL ll;         // create LL object
    ll.prepend(3); // call ll object member function
    return 0;
}
```

Or if you use pointer(just for sample of how to use pointer)

```
int main() {
    LL *ll = new LL();         // create LL object
    ll->prepend(3); // call ll object member function
    delete ll;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, this is the only way to call a function of a struct in c++? By creating a, in this case, linked list object and then calling the function through that object? Also, would ll -> prepend(3); work as well?

Comment: if you allocate resources, you need to destruct them accordingly.

Comment: @billz: Even if `prepend` were a *static* member of the class `LL`, the syntax `struct LL::prepend(3)` would still be invalid. Elaborate type specifier like `struct LL` cannot be used to refer to non-type members of the class. This syntax would be interpreted by the compiler as an attempt to refer to nested class type named `LL::prepend`. Since `prepend` is not a nested class type, the whole thing is ill-formed.

Comment: @AndreyT yup. can't agree more.